# onclick calling hide-div function not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've been fighting with this simple piece of code forever. I'm trying to use a `<button>` to call a simple JavaScript function to hide a `<div>`.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="close('wrong')">OK</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function close(ID)
{
    document.getElementById(ID).style.display="none";
}
```

I'm sure it's something really simple, I just can't, for the life of me, find it.

Comment: What is _not working_ ? Is an element with ID "wrong" exists ? Do you get an error message ?

Comment: @DidierG. - The tricky thing is there was no error, [it just didn't do anything](http://jsfiddle.net/H3pGz/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `close` function name to something else like `closeit` because it may be confusing it with the `window.close()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Try document.getElementById('wrong').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

Answer (score -1):

Let's do something in jQuery:

```
<button type="button" id="btn">OK</button>
<div id="myDiv">Div's contents here</div>
```

Now, you need just use the code below to do what you want:

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {    
   $("#btn").click(function () {
      $("#myDiv").hide();
   });
});
</script>
```

Notice: you can have some properties for hide() function: Fast and slow. This will affect on the speed of hiding action.

```
$("#myDiv").hide("slow");
```

I hope this can help you.