# JavaScript function close() {}

Tags: javascript

I've created a function in JS named close

```
function close() {...}
```

and have an onclick call

```
onclick="close()"
```

but it won't work. If I rename the function to whatever, it works. Could it be that it is forbidden to use a function in JS named close() ?

Comment: you have made it as ( function close() {} ) ,it is supposed to be an IIFE which has to be called right away,like ( function close() {} ) (),this if you are using it for click functionality i suggest make it function close(){}

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550828/onclick-calling-hide-div-function-not-working

Comment: @adeneo: Nice one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close` is a method of [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). Like all objects from window, you can call it without `window` prefix.

```js
console.log(typeof close);
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to be used in an `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler, your function has to be a global. Don't call a global function `close`, because globals become properties of the `window` object,<sup>1</sup> and it has a property called `close` (referring to a host function that closes the window). You aren't allowed to overwrite that property, and so it's the built-in one that ends up getting used. (And then the close request is ignored, there are various reasons windows may not allow you to close them via code.) Use another name (or better yet: make it *not* a global and hook it up with modern event handling).

---

<sup>1</sup> Except in ES2015 and later if you use `let` or `const` or `class` to create the global.

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I do that sometimes (not consistently) when I think the answer is pretty thoroughly known already... No really good reason.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in the global scope, where inline event handlers live, there already is a [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) function that can't be overwritten, and you're calling that function, not your own function named `close()`